# Jquery Slider. Previous position

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm making slider with jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/JwmxK/

```
var slidePath = '.testSlider > div.slide';

var sliderDuration = 53000;

var rotate = setInterval(slideShow, sliderDuration);

$(slidePath).hide();

slideShowFirst();

$('.slider-block').hover(function() {
  clearInterval(rotate);
}, function() {
  rotate = setInterval(function() {
      slideShow();
  }, sliderDuration);
});

$('.control-right').click(slideShow);

$('.control-left').click(function() {

    $(slidePath + ':eq(-2)').fadeIn('slow');

    $(slidePath + ':last-child').fadeOut('slow').prependTo('.testSlider');
});

function slideShow() {

    $(slidePath + ':last-child').fadeOut('slow');

    $(slidePath + ':first-child').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.testSlider');
}

function slideShowFirst() {

    $(slidePath + ':first-child').appendTo('.testSlider').show();
}
```

In my slider there is simple Ken Burns like effect. With css animation the current slide image is rotating and zooming in.

When I go to the PREVIOUS slide, the current image returns to its original state in one second (the scale is 100% and no zoom), and then the previous slide appears. It looks ugly. When I go to the NEXT slide, I have no such problem.

What's wrong?

I tried to change control-left function on it:

```
$('.control-left').click(function() {

    $(slidePath + ':last-child').fadeOut('slow');

    $(slidePath + ':eq(-2)').fadeIn('slow');

    $(slidePath + ':last-child').prependTo('.reveSlider');
});
```

But I have no changes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing by last you mean the button called `.control-left` try this:

```
$('.control-left').click(function() {

    $(slidePath + ':eq(-2)').fadeOut('slow');  // change to .fadeOut()

    $(slidePath + ':last-child').fadeIn('slow').prependTo('.testSlider'); // change to fadeIn()
});
```

if that doesn't work , I'm not too sure with out your HTML , you can try this

```
$('.control-left').click(function() {
    $(slidePath + ':last-child').fadeOut('slow').prependTo('.testSlider');
    $(slidePath + ':eq(-2)').fadeIn('slow');    
});
```

see how they are flipped?  you should `fadeOut()` before `fadeIn()`

Comment: It's not works.. You can go to jsfiddle link to watch the problem.
The problem is not in jquery fade animation. Before I used css animations instead jquery animations and was the same problem...

Comment: If I use fadeOut() before fadeIn(), there is no animation at all

Comment: @user3724896 _ tried your fiddle , I do not understand what the problem is.  it seems to be working fine for me

Comment: The problem is solved. It was in prependTo. I had to add two appendTo functions for previous position instead of prependTo.